# iPhone - Portrait application but all orientation support for videos

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

Hey looking for some help on this problem.

Currently I'm developing an iPhone application which is locked to portrait orientation throughout, however there are some videos included in the app using the MPMoviePlayer.

I want these videos (which automatically show in fullscreen) to be supported for both portrait and landscape orientations.

Any detailed ideas on how I could go about this? Literally tearing my hair out.

Many thanks!

Comment: The idea is to "unlock it" for the screens you need it unlocked. But It depends on how you lock it "throughout". Please share...

Comment: At the moment I have only added support for portrait orientation (bottom home button)in the .plist file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the limitation from the plist.
2. In each of your view controllers, implement `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to return `YES` only for supported interface orientations.  You *must* return `YES` for at least one orientation (the normal portrait orientation in your case).  Examples abound if you are unclear on how to do this.
3. As @Till indicated, display your `MPMoviePlayerController` view using a view controller that supports all orientations in its `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` (just return `YES` from the method).

But note that users tend to dislike apps that force an orientation, so make sure you have a very good usability case for why you need to impose this restriction.  (The recommendation is you support all orientations except upside down on iPhone, so that the user doesn't try to, say, answer a call upside down.)

Answer (score 0):

Display the `MPMoviePlayerController` on the view of a modally presented `UIViewController` that allows all possible interface orientations. That way the rest of your app may remain as is (portrait only).